# html2canvas not including fetched image in downloaded png

Tags: reactjs, cors, html2canvas

I'm trying to use the movie db API to fetch a movie poster and allow the user to put text next to it, then allow them to download that component using html2canvas. The downloaded image works, it has the right colors and text just not the movie. The image fills it's container using a `background-image` style but I also tried using an `img` tag but that didn't work either.  Here is the download function:

```js
const handleDownload = async () => {
    const element = ref.current;
    const canvas = await html2canvas(element, {useCORS: true, allowTaint: true});

    const data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const link = document.createElement('a');

    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
      link.href = data;
      link.download = 'image.png';

      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
      window.open(data);
    }
  }
```

this is the error that I'm getting:
[image: Error]

Here is what it's supposed to capture:
[image: expected result]

Here is what it actually captures:
[image: result]

I tried using `background-image` style for the container and I also tried using an `img` tag and it was the same error. I also tried setting `useCORS` to `false` which also didn't work.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72246428/how-can-i-solve-the-html2canvas-image-cross-origin-issue

Comment: @ChristianUnnerstall Sorry for the late response. Yes it actually worked thanks a lot for that. I will update the question and mark it as solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was thanks to @ChristianUnnerstall

The problem was that it was being blocked by cors. I had to add `crossOrigin="anonymous"` to the img tag that was rendered from the imdb database:

```html
<img
    id="chosen-image"
    src={
        selectedMovieImg
        ? `${selectedMovieImg}?not-from-cache-please}`
        : ""
    }
    alt="movie poster"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
```

I had to add `?not-from-cache-please` so cors sees it as a different request and it will be rendered to the dom and `selectedMovieImg` is a variable that holds the imdb link to the resource!